# How DbContext and connections to DB should be implemented to handle load testing?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ef-core-2.2

I have recently start implementing some load testing.
I am using .NetCore, EF Core 2.2 and Postgres.

I am calling my test server (with`HttpClient` `client.PostAsync("/api/resource");`).

I found that few of my requests fails because of too many connections (`The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds)`). So I implemented such approach:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(optionsAction: optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Config.ConnectionString,
    optionsAction =>
    {
        optionsAction.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
    }));
```

it helped a bit, but still, when calling with e.g. 500 requestes I got errors.

I imagine, that it should work in a way, that e.g. if system is able to handle 100 requests at the same time (e.g. 100 connections to DB), the remaining requests (which uses `MyDbContext`) should wait (rather than fail).

So my questions are:

1. Is it normal that with high load, the requests will fail because of maximum of possible concurrent connections?
2. If above is true - the normal approach is to use `EnableRetryOnFailure`?
3. Is it possible to make other requests to wait in non blocking way (e.g. max 20 seconds) until there are some connections available?
4. Or maybe there is other configuration option (in EF core, or in MVC) to make other requests to wait for available connection (from connection pool) instead of failing with exception?

Comment: *Why* was the pool exhausted? Do you *really* need to execute 100 queries *concurrently* or are you keeping the connections open for longer than necessary? Keeping a transaction open for the duration of a request is a scalability killing *bug* for example. Recovery won't fix the bug, it will only try to recover from it - by creating even *more* connections.

Comment: Contexts and connections are meant to be short-lived. Instead of pessimistic concurrency, ie transactions, use optimistic concurrency. Long-lived transactions aren't needed with ORMs like EF Core and NHibernate anyway, the DbContext collects all changes and only needs to send them once to the server when `SaveChanges` is called. That call uses a transaction internally so no external transaction is needed

Comment: Also, note that enabling `EnableRetryOnFailure` to cope with resource exhaustion could make it even worse as you'll now have each query potentially trying 5 times instead of once.

Comment: 100 connections should be able to handle thousands of *concurrent* requests. Even if there's no available connection in the pool a request would only have to wait for a while. Definitely not 15 seconds. If 500 requests keep 100 connections open for *15 seconds* there's a serious problem.

Comment: Keeping transactions open for long means they block each other too. It could be that all those connections do nothing except wait for each other to finish.

Comment: if I remove "EnableRetryOnFailure" then I got DB error "53300: sorry, too many clients already".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in your application that makes it *not* return the connections to the pool after the transaction is done (a so-called “connection leak”).

100 connections is way too big for a connection pool (unless the machine has 100 cores and local SSDs).

The idea is that when you want to perform a database transaction, you get a connection from the pool, do your work, commit the transaction and return the connection to the pool. Normally the time an OLTP transaction takes inside the database is so short that you can easily handle thousands of concurrent user sessions that way.

This all hinges on the assumption that your transactions are short. If they are not, you may get a problem wil concurrency, because locks are held until a transaction ends. Moreover, long transactions can keep autovacuum from doing its life-saving work.

Comment: Looks like my app gets problem whenever I explicitly wrap execution in transaction. Without transaction, subsequent requests (5k) finishes quickly with few seconds. As soon as I wrap code in transaction, I either get pool exhausted ex, or too many connections error. However I can't see any obvious place why connections aren't returned to pool at the end of transaction. I am almost sure there is no deadlock (just select and inserts, no updates). Do you have any idea why connections may not return to pool?

Comment: That sounds like you forgot to close (commit or rollback) the transactions.

Comment: Ok, I found the ultimate cause. Connection string timeout is not time of how long the connection can last, but rather time how long a Thread (request) can wait for a connection from Pool. If I wrap whole req in trans, the connection is blocked (reserved) from pool for the whole transaction time. If I have 500req, and 50 conn pool, and each req takes 2seconds to complete, then the timeout has to be set to minimum 10seconds. If I have 5000 req, then the timeout has to be at least 100 seconds. P.s. I use pessimistic concurrency. Now I need to refactor to optimistic concurrency.

Comment: 2 seconds is way too long for a database transaction. It should be measured in milliseconds.

Comment: But for some reason I wrap whole request in transaction, and inside there are few selects (each around 200ms) some C# logic, 1 update, and 2 inserts. And the updates/inserts are based on previous selects, and I really need all of these to be ATOMIC. That's why all transaction is around 1-2secs

Comment: I see. You cannot expect good concurrency with long transactions like that. Maybe something can be optimized.

Comment: Yes, now when I understand what really happened, I will optimize. Thank you for your advices.